# Update local git to match origin

Tags: git, github

I pushed my `local` git to `origin`, and then made a `PR` from there to `upstream`. However, in the `PR` process I needed to make some changes. During this time a lot of other PR's were made and merged into the `upstream/master` and I made a mess when I tried adding them into my PR. Someone was able to cleanup the `origin/branch` so that the `PR` didn't have all of the extra commits included in my commit. However, I need to make a few more tweaks to the `PR` to satisfy `Travis`.

While someone cleaned up `origin/branch` for me, my local version on my computer is still a complete mess.  I need to get it to match the cleaned up `origin` so that I can make changes and `git push --force` to my PR.

### How do I update my local git repo to the cleaned up `origin/branch` so that it doesn't include the long list of other commits?

Note: If I wasn't in the middle of a PR, my instinct would be to just reclone the origin/branch

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```sh
 git reset --keep --hard origin/branch
```

And your commits made to the local branch should stay, this can be checked with:

```sh
git log
```

You should also have the option of

```sh
git pull
```

Then clean up the merge conflicts by deciding to keep the current change or incoming change

Comment: I did do the git pull origin branch, and it worked but the git commit history still contains ~100 git commits between my original commit for the PR and the cleanup commit I made. I am worried that if I make my next set of changes, and force-push, all of those commits will show up in my PR. Perhaps I should be trying to remove that erroneous merge that I made?

Comment: Reanswering: if you pulled from origin than all those commits already exist and will not show up in the PR. The only commits that will show are the commit you made and pushed. you can "git diff source branch..target branch" to see what will be in the PR